# How do I access some rows with the largest values from a dataframe in pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I`ve been learning pandas dataframe and want to access 10 rows having the largest tip which is one of the column in my dataframe.

Comment: I guess something like ```df.sort_values(by=['tip'],ascending=[False]).head(10)```?

Comment: yes thank you. found out df.nlargest(10, 'tip') works too.